# How do I transfer data from Text Boxes in a form to an Access Table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, ms-access-2007

I'm currently trying to write code for a form that has text boxes for a user to input the required data into which then with the use of button the data in the text boxes will be sent to an access table.

If you need any more information to help solve the problem I'm willing to provide it if you ask (I would upload pictures/screenshots but I need "10 reputation" apparently.

Comment: You'll likely get some assistance by posting code of what you tried and what is/isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim AccessConection As OleDbConnection

Private Sub btSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSave.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim mySql As String

    mySql = "INSERT INTO Customs (CustomName,Address) VALUES(@Name,@Address)"

    Try
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txAddress.Text)

        cmd.Connection = AccessConection
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = mySql
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Whatever you want to say..." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myDataBasePath As String = "C:\Users\user\Source\Workspaces\......\SOF003\Data.accdb" 'Here you put the full name of the database file (including path)
    'The next line is for Access 2003 .mdb files
    'Dim CadenaConection As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}", myDataBasePath)
    Dim CadenaConection As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}", myDataBasePath)
    AccessConection = New OleDbConnection(CadenaConection)
    AccessConection.open()
End Sub
```

End Class

btSave is the command button.
Customs is the table's name.
CustomName and Address are two fields.
txName and txAddress are two TextBox Control.

Obviously you should be careful with the data types (here I use only strings), validation, etc, etc... But, this is a starting point. If you search, you'll find another ways, more elaborated.